# Получить коды символов в строке

Tags: java

Как у переменной типа string по индексу получить коды символов? Понятно что обращаться в цикле к индексу. Как именно получить код и какой тип данных возвращается, int? Если можно дайте ссылку на описание функции.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь функцией [`charAt`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#charAt-int-). Она принимает индекс символа и возвращает символ (тип `char`). Его можно привести к типу `int`, если хотите.

```
String s = "Hello!";

char firstChar = s.charAt(0);
// firstChar == 'H'

int firstCharInt = (int) firstChar;
```

Comment: Здравствуйте, а нельзя сделать так: String str = "Hello"; int charInt = (int) str[0]; ?

Comment: К сожалению, нельзя, через квадратные скобки можно обращаться только к массивам.

Comment: А по какой таблице я получаю этот код?

Comment: И почему лучше не приводить? Я пробую написать hash функцию и получаю для начала код символа.

Comment: В Java всё в Юникоде

Comment: Откуда получается значение типа Int? Из таблицы Юникода.

Comment: Из [документации](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html): `The char data type is a single 16-bit Unicode character` . При преобразовании `char` в `int` получим номер символа в UTF16.

Comment: Это кодировка, для вывода же можно будет перевести в utf8 или другую, я так понимаю?

Comment: Для вывода куда? `PrintStream`, например, [умеет](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print(char)) выводить `char`, там ничего приводить не надо.

Comment: Вы сказали что не рекомендуется приводить к типу Int. я про это. Объясните пожалуйста.

Comment: Я уже удалил. Если вы пишите хеш функцию, то без приведения к `int` не обойтись.

Answer (score 0):

`char a = 'ϒ'; int b = (int)a; System.out.print(b)`
//978 номер символа

Comment: у символа `Y` номер 978? это в какой кодировке?

Comment: encoding utf-8. В Джаве все в уникоде