# Как перевести каждый символ из String в char //цифры Java

Tags: java, строки

Надо чтоб каждый символ в String s2 стал int (цифрой)

```
package com.company.Name.Rating;

import java.util.Scanner;

class Main {

    public static class NameRating {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Введите текст");
            String a = in.nextLine();
            String s2 = a.toLowerCase();
            


        }

    }
}
```

надо чтоб на выходе выходили sym1, sym2, sym3 и тд

Comment: Плохо гуглить не надо, гуглить надо хорошо.  Проблема в _данной формулировке_ абсолютно не понятна.  Чего вы хотели добиться представленным кодом, тоже непонятно.

Comment: Возможные дубликаты: [Получить коды символов в строке, 2017](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/678105/), [Как преобразовать текстовую переменную String в int?, 2019](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/941157/)

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: _Из чего_ должны выходить `sym1, sym2` и т.д?

Comment: Типа есть строчка
"О и я"  И надо чтоб на выходе было много 5 int на выходе, каждый символ чтоб был представлен числом

Answer (score 2):

Для получения кода символа в строке используйте функцию [codePointAt](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#codePointAt(int))

Пример:

```
String text = "Hello! Привет!";
System.out.println(text);

for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
    int codePoint = text.codePointAt(i);
    System.out.printf("%2s: %s = %s\n", i, text.charAt(i), codePoint);
}
```

Результат:

```
Hello! Привет!
 0: H = 72
 1: e = 101
 2: l = 108
 3: l = 108
 4: o = 111
 5: ! = 33
 6:   = 32
 7: П = 1055
 8: р = 1088
 9: и = 1080
10: в = 1074
11: е = 1077
12: т = 1090
13: ! = 33
```